# Audio player that plays randomly without repeating

Tags: android, audio, audio-player

Is there an audio player on `Android` that plays randomly without
repeating what was already played?

The default player often repeats
songs when playing randomly.

This functionality should be preserved when I delete a song during random playing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a resource [here](https://alternativeto.net/software/rhythmbox/?platform=android) which lists a number of alternatives from which you can choose for Android.

One fairly high on the list is [AIMP](https://alternativeto.net/software/aimp/) worth considering but you may find others to consider.

Comment: OK, I will try AIMP and let you know, if it works.

Comment: I installed it, and have to test it a few days, if it does not repeat songs. But it seems, that it creates some random list, so I think it should be on a good way. I will probably accept it in a few days.